# prevent swf games to open new browser windows

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have some free swf games and I want like to put them on my website. some of these games are opening new browser windows and I would like to find a way to stop it.
Is there any solution usng javascript or maybe by an swf loader to prevent opening new browser windows?

Thanks,
ezzamil

Comment: Have you tried to set the param <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" /> in your HTML?

Comment: yes I already have this tag

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to block flash's calls to the method navigateToURL() without editing the application itself. Loading it into another SWF will result nothing.

Publishing the SWF file with parameter `< param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" />` has no effect as well.

You best choice is to re-compile the SWF after removing all the navigateToURL() calls.